# Create an electron JS desktop app with python and react js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, reactjs, electron

I want to create a desktop app with Electron JS and form front end I can use React JS as I'm familiar with it. 
I have a good grasp of Python I checked over the internet but they all wanted me to create an API and run it on local I can do that and connect to react electron app but for distribution, I need the user to install Python as well. 
I know I can go for node js as a backend but I have a lot of work ready in Python like backend logic and the app will run on desktop only no need to connect to Internet for that. 
I need to know if I need user to install python as well. I don't want that.

Comment: There are two problems with that :
first you can only run an exe on windows.
seconds how are we going to run an exe with electron js I mean we could try to run it as command and pass function and variables there but they will be two apps one is exe and one is electron app and if we cannot merge them then they are two apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the user to have to install Python then you need to use something to package it together. Check out Pyinstaller, once you've created an exe it can be distributed and doesn't require the user to install Python

https://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: Yeah but then there will be two files one is python exe and electron app I can run the exe from the app and then start a server and then interact with it but the question remains that how do I make those two exe files one because a user can delete the exe file, I can try to place the exe on a server and when the user runs the app I'll place that exe in C drive and then start the server from there and work, and if the user deletes the file I can simply grab that from the server and place it there again. But is that legal I mean User doesn't know that I'm placing an exe

Comment: What's wrong with there being two exes though? Lots of software does that where there are separate exes for different purposes. A obvious example is software that updates, one exe is for running it and another is used to update the software. Another example is where services run semi-independantly and communicate via a broker such as Rabbit

Comment: Now that is a response I can work with thanks a lot I'll try to bundle my api into an exe and see if that works

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark the question as Answered if you're happy with the response

Answer (score 5):

I think this is exactly what you're looking for, it's a reusable Electron template that uses a React front-end with Redux & Redux Toolkit, and is integrated with Python/Flask for microservices. Packaging functions with build scripts are available for Windows and macOS.

You can just copy the parts you need or clone the template and use it.

https://github.com/iPzard/electron-react-python-template